# eco-friendly whipping siphon

Tags: equipment

I have been looking for a whipping for a while, but I am a bit put off by the N2O and CO2 cartridges as they don't have great reusability but can only be recycled, also because of the small size recycling is not very effective. Especially since I would have to ship the cartridges a long way to get recycled.

Are there any more eco-friendly alternatives?

Comment: Material requirements for these cartridges are pretty tight. They have to withstand lots of pressure while still being safe and comfortable for home use. Also, as you mention, the market is tiny. So I doubt that anybody has gone to the trouble to develop an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a siphon manufacturer that makes a pump model that doesn't use chargers, but I have never seen one and I can't find evidence of one online.

The most eco-friendly route would probably be to whip the cream with a mixer and use a pastry bag to pipe it onto things. You could either use a reusable bag or disposable bags which should be more easily recyclable.

Edited to add: There are countertop whipped cream dispensers that do not use chargers. You add cream to a cavity in the top and they dispense from a nozzle in the front when a button is pressed. These require counter space and electricity though, so they're not practical for everyone.